# hide/show div on image click with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show/hide div when click on an image. when I click on the image nothing happens. What is wrong with my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#close').click(function(){
    $('#main').show();
    $('#login').hide();
    });
</script>

<div style="float:right;"><a href="#">Close <img id="close" src="assets/close.png"></a></div>
```

Comment: multiple `id`'s, also `a` "absorbing" the click event.

Comment: still not working + fixed my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#close').live('click',function(){
            $('#main').show();
            $('#login').hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<div style="float:right;"><a id="close">Close <img src="assets/close.png" /></a></div>
```

Use the live function.
Also, I would target the a tag so the text also triggers it.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because when your script executes, the `close` image doesn't exist yet. Wrap your setup in a `$(document).ready` block

Slight update:
In a quick test on my own machine, calling `.click(..)` on the image tag didn't do anything. I changed it so the `close` element is actually the `<a>`, and things worked.

Relevant HTML:

```
 <a id="close" href="#">Close (image goes here)</a>
```

Comment: or $(function(){ //content });

Comment: Or you can place your `<script>` after the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't have the same ID multiple times.

Then:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#image').click(function(){
        $('#close').toggle();
        });
    </script>

    <div id="close" style="float:right;"><a href="#">Close <img id="image" src="assets/close.png"></a></div>
```

Of course this will hide your image also so you don't have anything to click on.. but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to using id vs class names there is a pretty good rule of thumb. If you are going to use it more than once in a template make it a class. In the case of main,login,header or footer an Id works fine but here I would use a class.

Now that is not what's causing your issue but I thought I would point that out. Your problem is probably because the selector is trying to find something that is not there yet. You have 2 choices

1.) Move your script to bottom of the page
2.) Wrap your code in a ready function (only executes once the dom is ready.

Here is an updated code example with my suggestions

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Click Handler</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            $('.close').click(function(){
                $('#main').show();
                $('#login').hide();
            });
        })

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div style="float:right;"><a href="#" class="close">Close <img src="assets/close.png" class="close"></a></div>


<div id="main" style="display:none;">Main</div>
<div id="login">Login</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery live is deprecated, jQuery documentation indicates to use .on("click", function(){

});

[jQuery .live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/)

[jQuery .on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)