# Show div on image click then hide it after x seconds

Tags: html, hide, show, fade, smoothing

I'm trying to show a div when an image is clicked and then hide it after a given number of seconds. I've found two separate code samples that match my needs but I don't have the knowledge to put them together.

**the code which makes content disappear after x seconds:**

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('#fadeout').hide(2000);
    }, 4000);
</script>
```

**The code which makes the div appear on imageclick:**

```
<SCRIPT>
function fade(div_id, button) {

    if(button.value == 'FadeOut') {
        $('#'+div_id).fadeOut('slow');
        button.value = 'FadeIn';
    }
    else {
        $('#'+div_id).fadeIn('slow');
        button.value = 'FadeOut';
    }
}

$('#sometext').fadeOut(2);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help:

```
$('#fadeout').hide(); // hide div
$('img').live('click', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); //cancel default action of click
    $('#fadeout').show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1000); //show div on img click then hide after 5 seconds
});
```

here's a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7X767/3/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'slow', you can use time value in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But I cant seem to get it working.

I want a div to dissapear after 5 seconds when i click the image (not slowly in 5 seconds but after 5 seconds slowly for like 1 second).

Cold you please send me a final code?

Thanks

Comment: Similar post is at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621126/hide-show-div-on-image-click-with-jquery)